# How to display the table name in a union query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

The following script is working well:

```
DECLARE  @SelectClause  VARCHAR(100)    = 'SELECT id_contato'
        ,@Query         VARCHAR(8000)   = '' 

SELECT @Query = @Query + @SelectClause + ' FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%zumbi' or TABLE_NAME like '%engajado%')
SELECT @Query = LEFT(@Query, LEN(@Query) - LEN(' UNION ALL '))
EXEC (@Query)
```

But I need a second column with the table name to identify where the information came from.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You're utilizing the `table_name` field already in your query, just need to add it to your `SELECT` and quote it properly so it comes back as string literal:

```
DECLARE  @SelectClause  VARCHAR(100)    = 'SELECT id_contato'
        ,@Query         VARCHAR(8000)   = '' 

SELECT @Query = @Query + @SelectClause + ','''+Table_Name+''' AS Table_Name FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ' UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_NAME LIKE '%zumbi' or TABLE_NAME like '%engajado%')
SELECT @Query = LEFT(@Query, LEN(@Query) - LEN(' UNION ALL '))
EXEC (@Query)
```

Updated quotes, works for me in SQL Server.

Comment: the result i'm getting is something like that:

`SELECT id_contato, 'Table_Name' AS Table_Name FROM disparo_disparo_1878_prospect_zumbi UNION ALL SELECT id_contato (...)`

the name of the table is not being shown.

Comment: @Richard I might have updated the quotes after you checked it, definitely had it mixed around initially but should work now, checks out for me in SQL Server at least.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean, that's your current result, but what do you want instead? Since you're unioning them together, the alias will be static as it comes from the top query in the `UNION`.

Comment: nvm... it worked. Thank you guys. I'm just wondering why the ending is being cut (maybe the varchar size)... but I'm working on it... I'll put a reply soon.

Comment: ok, I increased the varchar to max and now its running perfectly. thank you again for the quick help.